# How to locate position/coordinates of faces in photo through code?

Tags: image, pixel, face-detection

I know about face.com and its cool API. But it only identifies the people in the photo. I really dont need that. I want to able to detect the position (as in x,y,width and height) of face(s) in a given 2d photo. If anyone know of an ongoing project, of available projects, please help me out with some links, tips and or advice. Deeply appreciate that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OpenCV Face detector. It gives x,y,width,height